# Is there a way to keep an instance of Excel open, even after all workbooks have been closed?

Tags: excel, vba

**Condition**: Currently, I have two separate Excel instances - `xlApp` and `xlApp2`.

- `xlApp` is the Excel instance in which my personal workbook was
  opened.
- `xlApp2` is the new Excel instance created through the VBA code
  in my workbook to house other workbooks.

**Issue**: If I close my personal workbook in `xlApp`, and open a new workbook, it will be added to `xlApp`, which is what I am looking for; however, if I close `xlApp` by pressing the "X" or end the task in Task Manager, then any new workbook I open will be added to `xlApp2`, which is not what I am looking for.

**Goal**: The program should be keeping the `xlApp` instance open or create a new instance if it is closed, so that new workbooks will be added to it rather than to `xlApp2`. Would this be possible in VBA?

```
Public Sub keepExcelInstance()

Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
Dim xlApp2 as Excel.Application

Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")    'Get the current instance of Excel.

Set xlApp2 = New Excel.Application              'Create a separate instance of Excel.

End Sub
```

Comment: I think creating it with [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) might be worth a shot. Also `Set xlApp = Application` gets you the current instance, but then why copy an object reference that's already global? If the global `Application` object is called `Application` everywhere, the code is that much easier to follow ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Interesting, I will have to try that and explore Shell.

Comment: Note you'll need `GetObject` to retrieve the spawned instance - there are gotchas, but you'll find them all on this site =)